# trying to update Xamarin.Forms to 2.3 but getting Access to the path 'Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.dll' is denied

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

In Visual Studio 2015 I'm trying to run the NuGet update for Xamarin.Forms but it fails at

`Access to the path 'Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.dll' is denied.`

I tried

- running as Admin
- Made sure file isn't "read only"
- Delete the file
- manually Clean/Rebuild

Comment: sounds like the local file is read only have you tried finding that folder right clicking and un checking read only

Comment: What happens if you reboot, then do a nuget update before you run your app after that reboot?

Comment: I believe this was correct. I think calling it dirty names helped some too.